# Distance between lattices of invariant subspaces of matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

For a linear transformation $A: C^n \to C^n$ let $Inv(A)$ be the lattice of all $A$-invariant subspaces. In work I.~Gohberg, L.~Rodman "On the Distance between Lattices of Invariant Subspaces of Matrices" analysis the distanse between $Inv(A)$ and $Inv(B)$ defined as follows:
$$
dist(Inv(A),Inv(B))=\max\Big(\sup\limits_{M\in Inv(A)}\ \ \inf\limits_{L\in Inv(B)}||P_L-P_M||, \sup\limits_{M\in Inv(B)}\ \ \inf\limits_{L\in Inv(A)}||P_L-P_M||\Big),
$$
where $P_N$ is orthogonal projector on the subspace $N$ in $C^n$.

I can not quite understand this definition. Why is there symmetry?
Maybe someone met geometric Interpretation of these definition.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the Hausdorff distance between the two sets. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

Answer (score 3):

Essentially this is nothing else than the Hausdorff distance between these lattices (as sets of subspaces) if you consider $\|P_L-P_M\|$ as the distance between subspaces $L$ and $M$.